# Toast notifications per day

Tags: windows-phone-7, push-notification, toast, mpns

Quick question, I read that Microsoft throttles toast notifications to 500 per day per subscription... I'm just checking... but thats per phone right? Not per server sending out toasts? so if I have 1000 devices receiving 1 toast thats ok, but sending 1000 toasts to 1 device==bad ... right?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like this is per-phone. You can however remove this limit if you authenticate your server. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402558%28VS.92%29.aspx):

> We recommend setting up an authenticated web service to send your
>   notifications to the Microsoft Push Notification Service, because
>   communication occurs over an HTTPS interface for better security.
>   Authenticated web services do not have a daily limit on the number of
>   push notifications they can send. Unauthenticated web services, on the
>   other hand, are throttled at a rate of 500 push notifications per
>   subscription per day. For more information, see Setting Up an
>   [Authenticated Web Service to Send Push Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941099%28VS.92%29.aspx) for Windows
>   Phone.

Comment: ah cool I thought that might be the case. I think 500 is fine for a feild service application... I doubt anyone will get more than 500 jobs in one day :) cheers (and it looks like you can't self certify, so it might not be cost effective to do that)

Answer (score 1):

> Push notifications can operate in unauthenticated or authenticated
>   mode. In unauthenticated mode, the number and frequency of
>   notifications allowed through the Microsoft Push Notification Service
>   is throttled (unauthenticated push notifications are currently limited
>   to 500 per day, per channel).
>
> For push notifications in authenticated mode, developers first must
>   register a certificate with the Push Notification Service through
>   Windows Phone Marketplace. The certificate must be issued by a
>   Microsoft-trusted root certificate authority. This certificate then is
>   used to establish a Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) connection between the
>   web service and the Push Notification Service. Authenticated push
>   notifications are not throttled.

-> Got it from MSDN so it is per phone. You can also find more information about how to be in authenticated mode.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the 500 limit is per app per phone.

If you need to send more than that you'll need to get a certificate and sign your notifications.